# Get the diagonal of a matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to extract the diagonal of a square matrix in TensorFlow? That is, for a matrix like this:

```
[
 [0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8]
]
```

I want to fetch the elements: `[0, 4, 8]`

In numpy, this is pretty straight-forward via [np.diag](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

In TensorFlow, there is a [diag function](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops.md#diag), but it only forms a new matrix with the elements specified in the argument on the diagonal, which is not what I want.

I could imagine how this could be done via striding... but I don't see striding for tensors in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

with tensorflow 0.8 its possible to extract the diagonal elements with `tf.diag_part()` (see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#diag_part))

**UPDATE**

for tensorflow >= r1.12 its `tf.linalg.tensor_diag_part` (see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/tensor_diag_part))

Comment: I updated the link. It seems they renamed / moved the function to the linalg-package

Answer (score 5):

Currently it is possible to extract diagonal elements with [tf.diag_part](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#diag_part). Here is their example:

```
"""
'input' is [[1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 2, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 3, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 4]]
"""

tf.diag_part(input) ==> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Old answer (when diag_part) was not available (still relevant if you want to achieve something that is not available now):

After looking though the [math operations](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops.md) and [tensor transformations](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.md), it does not look like such operation exists. Even if you can extract this data with matrix multiplications it would not be efficient (get diagonal is `O(n)`).

You have three approaches, starting with easy to hard.

1. Evaluate the tensor, extract diagonal with numpy, build a variable with TF
2. Use [tf.pack](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.md#pack) in a way Anurag suggested (also extract the value 3 using `tf.shape`
3. Write your own [op in C++](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.md), rebuild TF and use it natively.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the tf.diag_part()

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.ones(shape=[3, 3])
    x_diag = tf.diag_part(x)
    print(sess.run(x_diag ))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably is a workaround, but works.

```
>> sess = tensorflow.InteractiveSession()
>> x = tensorflow.Variable([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>> x.initializer.run()
>> z = tensorflow.pack([x[i,i] for i in range(3)])
>> z.eval()
array([1, 5, 9], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this operation can be tremendously slow, not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather) operation.

```
x = tensorflow.Variable([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
x_flat = tf.reshape(x, [-1])  # flatten the matrix
x_diag = tf.gather(x, [0, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, a mask can be a nice way to `cancel' off diagonal elements of the matrix, especially if you plan in reducing it anyway:

```
mask = tf.diag(tf.ones([n]))
y = tf.mul(mask,y)
cost = -tf.reduce_sum(y)
```