# Is there a way to extract the k diagonals of an (k,n,n) tensor in TensorFlow or Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, diagonal

In the post [Get the diagonal of a matrix in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700049/get-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix-in-tensorflow) for an square matrix (n,n), one sugestion are use the function tf.diag_part(tensor). But if the tensor are dimensions (k,n,n) ? Exist any way to do that? The necessary output are the k diagonals of the k square matrix(n,n) of tensor, that is , I need one output of dimension (k,n). Some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.map_fn`, from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

> Map on the list of tensors unpacked from elems on dimension 0.

So you just need to map `tf.diag_part`:

```
a = tf.placeholder(shape=[100, 10, 10], dtype=tf.float32)
diags = tf.map_fn(tf.diag_part, a, parallel_iterations=100)
```

The shape of `diags` is `(100, 10)`

Note: `parallel_iterations` should ideally be equal to `k` in your case for maximum performance.